# Assign double to std::string -- no compile error?

Tags: c++

Why isn't the compiler complaining about this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string a;
   a = 2.3;
   std::cout << "A:" << a << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

GCC, MSVC don't seem to be concerned about this at all,
even though it is clearly wrong and doesn't actually work anyway!

The output is:

```
A:
```

OUCH !  Lead to an undetected error in my program.

Comment: Turn on warnings? Clang emits the following: `warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'char' changes value from 2.3 to 2 [-Wliteral-conversion]`

Comment: It's doing what you told it to. Change the double value to 65.3 and it will output `A:A` (65 is the ASCII value of the letter `A`).

Comment: In my GCC (4.82) even `-Wall -Wextra` does not turn this warning on `-Wconversion` needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::string` has an overload for [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) that takes a character. When you pass an argument to a function by value (i.e, an operator), [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) occurs. In copy initialization, [standard conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), also known as an "implicit conversion", may be used to the convert the value. In this case, your double is being silently converted to a char so that it may be used in `operator=`.

For GCC, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` will not make a diagnostic appear. You can try `-Wfloat-conversion`, which is enabled by `-Wconversion`. Example:

```
main.cpp:11:10: warning: conversion to 'char' alters 'double' constant value 
[-Wfloat-conversion]
        a = 3.2;
```

Alternatively, use braces to force a narrowing conversion error.

```
s = {4.3};
// warning: narrowing conversion of '4.2e+1' from 'double' to 'char' inside { } 
// [-Wnarrowing]
```

Comment: Could the writers of std::string not have made this constructor `explicit` I wonder?

Comment: Given that "cast" is "explicit conversion", "implicit cast" doesn't really make a whole lot of sense, and the page you link to has stopped calling it that outside of the URL back in 2012.

Comment: @TT There is no constructor involved.  The implicit conversion is from `double` to `char`.

Comment: The older GCC 4.7.2 doesn't have -Wfloat-conversion, so I'll have to watch for the problem once I've upgraded to GCC 4.9 or Clang.  Thanks for the good answer.  I wish now that there was no operator=(char)...

Answer (score 6):

The compiler will do an implicit conversion from `2` to the equivalent ASCII char: "`start of text`" (therefore you can't see anything).

Maybe you have disabled the warning of your compiler. Try to turn them on.

Answer (score 4):

> GCC:

compile in gcc with option `[-Wconversion]`, then you'll see that the compiler will issue the warning:

`warning: conversion to 'char' alters 'double' constant value [-Wfloat-conversion]`

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc8d6d592c74c116)

> *MSVC don't seem to be concerned about this at all:*

VS2013 produces the following warning:

`warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'char', possible loss of data`

> even though it is clearly wrong and doesn't actually work anyway!

It's not wrong, it's just an implicit conversion from the truncated `double` 2.3 to a `char` with ASCII code 2 [(start of text)](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately GCC with `-Wconversion` produces a lot more warnings than needed, for example for the code `short x = 0; x += 10;`.

Comment: `-Wconversion` enables `-Wfloat-conversion`. To avoid the problem mentioned by @Anton, just do `-Wfloat-conversion`.

Comment: So a = 2.0 wouldn't give that error (because the value is not altered)? That's unfortunate.